# How would I create a rotation speed controller

Tags: animation, drivers

So I was trying to Create a Animated set of gears that play continuously through out a project. I have managed to do so using drivers a number of ways. (setting the frames or position of a moving empty on a graph with a generator set to have them move continually along one axis) But I need a Custom Property Variable that can accelerate and decelerate the speed of the gears rotation. If I just multiply the custom property by the Constant rotation speed then when I lower the value over time the gear reverses direction as the number is decreasing which I don't want. Can some one point me toward how I would make a custom property that works in the following way. 0 = no speed. 1 = normal speed. 10 = 10x speed. -1 normal speed reverse ect... I'm thinking I will need to use expressions of some kind but I'm a bit stuck as to how I would set this up. :/

Comment: If you want to do this live, it's not possible without something like Animation Nodes.  In order to know the current rotation of a gear, knowing the current speed is not enough-- you need to know the complete history of speed.  And drivers and constraints don't know history.

Comment: how would I do this with animation nodes then. I do have that.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not competent enough to answer that :(  Hopefully someone else can.